# Jquery checked and printing on div

Tags: jquery

```
    <script>
    $(":checkbox").click(function () {
          var str = "";
          $("input:checked").each(function () {
                str += ($(this).val())  + " ";
              });
          $("div").text(str);
        })
        .click();
</script>


  div { color:red; }
  </style>
```

**why does not work?** I added the last nell'head jquery but I do not print anything
thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me in FF, chrome and IE 7-9. I've never had problems using change() on a checkbox

http://jsfiddle.net/c2fE9/

Selectors could probably be optimized, but that won't stop code working

Comment: Hey, you're right, your fiddle is working for me too. It never occurred to me using `change` on a checkbox, though.

Comment: I wanted to ask if you could use the same script with the radio of course only if checked. Thanks

Comment: yes to radio.. as I mentioned, selectors would be better if optimized. Using input:checkbox is for example more efficient, but class would definitely help too

Comment: Sorry again but I could lend a hand, look at this link http://jsfiddle.net/Simone/6s8fZ/
The radio does not deselect more, Why?

Comment: is same demo i made, not sure what I'm looking for

Comment: strange! I shared another link with little changes, but different from yours. At this link: http://jsfiddle.net/Simone/6s8fZ/

Comment: I do not understand the last comment what do I do?

Comment: My problem now is that clicking radio input and unchecked its does not change the status, remains forever

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because your checkboxes will never trigger the `change` event. That event is only triggered when an input's *value* changes, and the checkboxes' values don't usually change, only their state change. Replace `change` with `click` and it should work.

Comment: does not work the same. if I add the click event I have left with the checkbox enabled